# How to pass SIGINT to a process created in java?

Tags: java

I've created a process using `Runtime.exec`, and I need a way of killing the process as one would using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The process I've started is a video recording tool that specifically looks for a keyboard interrupt in order to write the video file and close all connections cleanly. Unfortunately, `Process.destroy` doesn't do this. Is there any other way of doing it in java, using the handle I have of the process?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to do a kill command on the process to send a signal.  I don't think Java has a way to do that directly.  You may be able to Runtime.exec() the kill command itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a not-too-clean solution, for instance writing a small shell script that invokes `` kill -2 `pidof executable` `` (or `killall -2 executable` if you do not mind killing every process). A much cleaner solution would be to retrieve the process ID from java, but I do not know how (or if) it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now...get the output of 'ps' along with some greping, and use that with 'kill -2'. I remember, though, seeing some javadoc which described a method that gets all the processes started from the current virtual machine (or something to that effect), and hence my question.

Answer (score -1):

You should be kill the process when the Java gets killed using following!

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec();  
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {  
            process.destroy();  
        }  
}));  
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: it wasn't me, but the OP says *"Unfortunately, Process.kill() doesn't do this."* and ... I assume ... he is referring to `Process.destroy()` because there is no `kill()` method.  (FWIW, it is not specified what signal `Process.destroy()` uses, but my guess is that is not SIGINT, because a child process could ignore that one, meaning that the child won't be destroyed.)

Comment: @Stephen C: Yeah, my bad, it's Process.destroy() I was referring to :-)

Comment: `destroy()` emits SIGTERM, not SIGINT.

Comment: The question is how to emit SIGINT. As others mentioned, the destroy method emits SIGTERM.